# Inconsistent derivatives with respect to a function when using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am trying to derive an expression for some partial derivatives in two different ways, but they seem to lead to inconsistent results.

I have got the Cartesian components of a two-dimensional position vector $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and I need to evaluate their sensitivity with respect to the angle $\varphi(t)$, which is defined as
$$\varphi(t) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y(t)}{x(t)} \right)$$

According to the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291376/differentiate-with-respect-to-a-function),
by using the chain rule, I can compute the partial derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $\varphi(t)$ as
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi} = \frac{\partial x / \partial x}{\partial \varphi / \partial x} = \frac{1}{\partial \varphi / \partial x} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y(t)}{x(t)} \right) \right) \right)^{-1} = -\frac{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}{y(t)} $$

However, by expressing the position in polar coordinates
$$ x(t) = r(t) \cos(\varphi(t)) $$
$$ y(t) = r(t) \sin(\varphi(t)) $$
the derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $\varphi(t)$ appears to be
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi} = -r(t) \sin(\varphi(t)) = -r(t) \frac{y(t)}{r(t)} = -y(t) $$
This is a completely different result from the one obtained using the chain rule. So, which one is correct and why? Also, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20884/polar-coordinates-and-derivatives

Comment: OK, thanks @BertrandEinsteinIV, that actually helps a bit. So, which is the right derivative of x with respect to phi?